# How can you blend two videos (with their both audio) in a single video using gstreamer?

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, pipeline, blending

I currently know how to blend two videos into one, it was very hard to learn how to do this (more than 30 continuous hours researching), I've used the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=candidate.webm ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=680,height=480 ! compositor name=comp sink_1::xpos=453 sink_1::ypos=340 ! vp9enc ! webmmux ! filesink location=out.web filesrc location=interviewer.webm ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=140 ! comp.
```

In this case I'm blending two videos so that the second of them is in the right bottom corner, and the first one is the "background". Well, does somebody knows how can I get both audios in the same file too? I hope someone find useful my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The `audiomixer` element does take multiple audio streams and mixes them into a single audio stream.